# Update form field in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, forms

I have a form on my site which is used to upload images. The form works, but the Javascript isn't acting how I expect it to. What I want it to do, is when I select an image using the "Browse" button, to update the neighbouring input field with the filename. Can anyone see why this wouldn't be working?

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <span class="btn btn-danger btn-file">
            Browse… <input type="file" name="Image" multiple="">
        </span> 
    </span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control filename" readonly="">
</div>
```

And here's the Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('change', '.btn-file :file', function() {
        var input = $('.filename'),
            numFiles = input.get(0).files ? input.get(0).files.length : 1,
            label = input.val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');
        input.trigger('fileselect', [numFiles, label]);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You say `input = $('.filename')` which is the textbox, but you are trying to get the files from that input instead of the file input. You'll probably want something like `$(this)[0].files`

Comment: ok, and what do i need to do to output that to the textbox? I will update my code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use This Code It will help you

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<style>
.btnEdit{display:none;}
</style>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('change', '.btn-file :file', function() {
      var fileName = $('#uploadfile').val();
      $('.filename').val(fileName);
    });
</script>
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <span class="btn btn-danger btn-file">
            Browse… <input id = 'uploadfile' type="file" name="Image" multiple="">
        </span> 
    </span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control filename" readonly="">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Ishan, that has worked perfectly. Many Thanks.

Comment: You are always welcome. Please have a look on it this one is perfect for your requirement http://jsfiddle.net/28yy975f/

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will work for you.

```
$(document).on('change', '.btn-file :file', function(value) {
console.log(value);
    var input = $('.filename'),
        numFiles = value.target.files ? value.target.files.length : 1,
        label = value.target.files[0].name.replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');
    input.val(label);
});
```

I have added **value** as argument in change event, after that variable is used to take file name from element.

For testing you can test from here : http://jsfiddle.net/u4od6b2L/